# Laptop with a touchscreen: How to configure specific screen gestures in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, multi-touch, touchscreen

I got nice laptop with a touchscreen (HP Envy TM m7). It came pre-installed with Windows 8 and I promptly put Ubuntu on it. Due to some issues, 13.04 wouldn't work so I went with the 12.04.02 LTS instead.

The touchscreen worked out of the box when it comes to clicking, but I wonder if there is a way to add more tablet-like gestures such as 2-finger pinch zooming, or scrolling with a one-finger swipe, or cycling through open applications by swiping from the screen edge etc.

Google results are in most cases only concerned with touchpad gestures.

Here is the weird thing: Two-finger gestures work on the touchpad (e.g. the two-finger scrolling) and can be changed in the "Mouse and Touchpad" panel. Three-finger gestures such as pinch to maximize or Four-finger tap to open dash do only work on the touchscreen.

What I cannot seem to configure is two-finger scrolling on the touchscreen, as there is in general no settings panel for the touchscreen.

Comment: You can try this program: [easystroke](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/easystroke). It lets you define custom gestures. Also, have a look at this: [Ginn](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/Ginn), install it from [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ginn/)

Answer (score 2):

You can install packages like [Easystroke](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/easystroke) & [Ginn](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ginn/) for it to work.

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate how those packages should be used to enable touchscreen scrolling?

Comment: Easystroke is a gesture-recognition application for X11. I tried ginn, but it cannot load: `error subscribing to gestures`. I heard for ginn, there is only one way - remove guesture support from unity sources, recompile, disable unity updates and install ginn/touchegg.